# jQuery toggle multiple classes on one element from 3 buttons

Tags: jquery

Ok so i am looking to make 3 different buttons control the class for one element. But only one class can be used at any one time so i need to remove the two classes not being used.

The buttons:

```
<ul class="group">
<li> <a href="#" class="small-btn">Small</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="med-btn">Medium</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="large-btn">Large</a> </li>
</ul>
```

My content wrapper:

```
<div id="main_content" class="large">
content here
</div>
```

I can't quite work out in my head how i'd check against the two other classes and remove them? Is there a way to store classes as a variable in jQuery? Help appreciated..

Comment: If there should only ever be 1 class on the `#main_content` element you can remove all classes by using `removeClass()` with no parameter, then add the class required. No need for any checking.

Comment: Or just change the attribute value as in my answer. That resets the whole attribute.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, i didn't know i could leave the parameter blank :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a data-* attribute to specify the target class name

```
<ul class="group">
<li> <a href="#" class="small-btn" data-class="small">Small</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="med-btn" data-class="medium">Medium</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="large-btn" data-class="large">Large</a> </li>
</ul>
```

then

```
$('ul.group a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#main_content').attr('class', $(this).data('class'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yN2PP/)

Comment: This feels cleaner than the other solutions, keeping the parent class independent of the child class.  The child classes might not even be required.

Comment: This is how I'd do it but I'd use delegation instead `$('.group').on('click', 'a', function(){...}));`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and clean solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[class$='btn']").click(function() {
        var $container = $('#main_content');
        $container.removeClass();

        var cls = $(this).attr('class');
        $container.addClass(cls.substring(0, cls.indexOf("-")));    
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/eudyY/

Comment: generally when I see the `$...` variable naming convention, I take it to mean its a jQuery element. Your `$class` variable violates this convention (and is global)

Comment: and if you're gonna grab the new class from the link class, `class.replace('-btn', '')` would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: agree on $class variable

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** removed my other approaches, leaving this one (my fav. so far ;-)

```
$(".group").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('-btn','');
  $('#main_content').attr('class', newClass);   
});
```

Comment: Thank you man, really helped me out. Only went with the answer above due to it being slightly cleaner, but appreciated man

Comment: Ah, thanks for the kind words. The above answer is the one I'd go for myself as well. I'd like to think I'd have come up with something a bit closer to that in a 3rd iteration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, albeit untested:

```
$('ul.group a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    $('#main_content').attr('class', $.trim($self.text().toLowerCase()));
});
```

This assumes the new class to add is the text of the element, rather than the class-name of the element being clicked, which isn't clear from your question, but if you'd rather the class of the clicked element became the class of the `#main_content` then I'd suggest, instead, the following:

```
$('ul.group a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    $('#main_content').attr('class', self.className);
});
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).